# Erro em metodo para validar login

Tags: java, api, rest, login

Bom dia, estou fazendo um projeto java/react com apirest e estou tendo dificuldades para validar o login
ERRO:

```
Caused by: Error : 1008, Position : 0, Sql = SELECT * FROM TB_SGC_USUARIO WHERE login_usuario = :1  and senha_usuario = :2 , OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM TB_SGC_USUARIO WHERE login_usuario = ? and senha_usuario = ?, Error Msg = ORA-01008: nem todas as variáveis são limitadas
```

Segue os codigos:
UsuarioTO:

```
package br.com.fiap.resource;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class UsuarioTO {

    private String nom_usuario;
    private String login_usuario;
    private String senha_usuario;
    
    
    public String getNom_usuario() {
        return nom_usuario;
    }
    public void setNom_usuario(String nom_usuario) {
        this.nom_usuario = nom_usuario;
    }
    public String getLogin_usuario() {
        return login_usuario;
    }
    public void setLogin_usuario(String login_usuario) {
        this.login_usuario = login_usuario;
    }
    public String getSenha_usuario() {
        return senha_usuario;
    }
    public void setSenha_usuario(String senha_usuario) {
        this.senha_usuario = senha_usuario;
    }
    public UsuarioTO() {
        super();
    }
    public UsuarioTO( String login_usuario, String senha_usuario) {
        super();
        this.login_usuario = login_usuario;
        this.senha_usuario = senha_usuario;
    }
}
```

UsuarioDAO:

```
    package br.com.fiap.dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.fiap.resource.UsuarioTO;


public class UsuarioDAO {

        

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.fiap.com.br:1521:ORCL";
    private static final String USERNAME = "login";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "senha";
    private Connection con;
    PreparedStatement rs = null; 
    List<UsuarioTO> validarLogin = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public UsuarioDAO() throws SQLException{
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    }
    public List<UsuarioTO> validacao(UsuarioTO u) {
    try {
        List<UsuarioTO> validarLogin = new ArrayList<>();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM TB_SGC_USUARIO WHERE login_usuario = ? and senha_usuario = ?";
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
    
    
        while(rs.next());{
            UsuarioTO buscaUsuario = new UsuarioTO(
                rs.getString("login_usuario"),
                rs.getString("senha_usuario")
                );
        validarLogin.add(buscaUsuario);
        rs.close();
        con.close();
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return validarLogin;
        }
                
        
    
    public UsuarioTO loginDAO(UsuarioTO u) {
        validacao(u);
        for (int i = 0; i < validarLogin.size(); i++) {
            if (validarLogin.get(i).getLogin_usuario().equals(u.getLogin_usuario())
                && validarLogin.get(i).getSenha_usuario().equals(u.getSenha_usuario())){
                return validarLogin.get(i);
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

UsuarioBO:

```
package br.com.fiap.bo;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import br.com.fiap.dao.UsuarioDAO;
import br.com.fiap.resource.UsuarioTO;

public class UsuarioBO {

        UsuarioDAO ud = null;   
        
        public UsuarioTO validacao(UsuarioTO u) throws SQLException {
            ud = new UsuarioDAO();
            return ud.loginDAO(u);
        }       
    }
```

Já tentei resolver de varias formas, mas o metodo está retornando NULL e dando o erro que eu apresentei acima.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, a mensagem da Exception está sendo bem descritiva sobre o problema:
`nem todas as variáveis são limitadas`

Porém, concordo, poderia ser mais claro.\

Seguindo...

Sua classe `UsuarioDAO.java` está:

**1.** Montando a query sql nesse momento:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TB_SGC_USUARIO WHERE login_usuario = ? and senha_usuario = ?";
```

Nela tem-se dois caracteres **?**(nada mais são do que parâmetros)

- login_usuario = **?**
- senha_usuario = **?**

Na sua query, você *precisa substituir os parâmetros* **?** pelo *valor real* **antes** de fazer a requisição no banco e **Isto é o que não está sendo feito.**

**2.** Abaixo não é feito a substituição do **?** pelos **valores reais**:

```java
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
```

Desta forma, repare, sua query está exatamente assim:
*"SELECT * FROM TB_SGC_USUARIO WHERE login_usuario = **?** and senha_usuario = **?**"*;\

Na sua lógica, você desenhou que ia fornecer **dois argumento**s.
Um para preencher o **login_usuario** e outro para **senha_usuario**.
Então você preparou a query, **mas**, *não fez a atribuição destes argumentos*.

Desta forma a *query sql* chega no *banco* e o *Oracle* lê:
"- Hm, ele disse que ia passar o valor do login_usuario e do senha_usuario mas não passou. O que que houve? Não sei resolver isso não."

Normalmente usamos a **PreparedStatement** para esta finalidade.
Para preparar, tratar, fazer o devido tratamento dos escapes/caracteres que serão passados nos **?**.
Para, aí sim, com a query OK, fazermos a chamada no banco.
Seria algo mais ou menos assim no seu caso:

```java
//início omitido
public List<UsuarioTO> validacao(UsuarioTO u) {
  try {
    List<UsuarioTO> validarLogin = new ArrayList<>();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM TB_SGC_USUARIO WHERE login_usuario = ? and senha_usuario = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, u.geLogin_usuario());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, u.getSenha_usuario());
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
//restante omitido
```

Ou... poderia fazer direto:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TB_SGC_USUARIO WHERE login_usuario = " + u.geLogin_usuario() + "  and senha_usuario = " + u.geSenha_usuario();
```

*Particulamente* o mais seguro é fazer uso do **PreparedStatement**, por alguns motivos já listados acima.